# Revocation of users in encrypted storage system?

Tags: aes, multiple-encryption, secure-storage

How can you design an encrypted storage system, that allows adding and removing users without sharing a common secret and having to re-encrypt everything when a user is removed?

#### My partial idea is:

Each user has a RSA key pair. Shared folders have an encryption key (*EK1*), that is encrypted with each user's public key. If a user uploads a file, an HMAC-SHA using *EK1* is calculated over the file contents. The file is then encrypted using a random nonce (*RN*), random key (RK) and AES256-GCM(*RN*, *RK*, data). The *RK* is then encrypted using *EK1* and prepended to the encrypted file, together with the *RN*. The encrypted file is then stored under its HMAC-SHA (this also enables deduplication).

If you remove an user from the shared folder, you can generate a new shared folder encryption key (*EK2*) and encrypt that new key with the public keys of the remaining users.

#### Problem:

If a user tries to upload the same file again, it now has a different HMAC-SHA because of the new *EK2* which is different from *EK1*. And decrypting is now also impossible, as *EK1* has been replaced by *EK2*.

#### Question:

How can you model such a storage system, that enables removing users without re-encrypting everything?

Comment: I hope “HMAC-SHA” is HMAC-SHA2 or KMAC-SHA3. While HMAC-SHA1 isn’t affected by the published collision attacks on SHA1, it effectively means SHA1 should no longer be used for any _new_ development but only for backwards compatibility. If you meant “some generic secure MAC I haven’t chosen yet” the convention would be to just call that function “MAC”